# Angular create new scope inside service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that uses ngDialog (that's the only purpose of the service - to show common dialogs: alerts, confirms, etc). ngDialog requires scope object to be passed as parameter to interpolate dialog's template.
So I need to create a scope, assign it's properties and pass to ngDialog.open.
The problem is I can't inject $rootScope (or $scope) into service, and scope.$new is the only way I could find to create an empty scope.
When I inject $rootScope like this

```
    myService.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'ngDialog'];
```

I get error: Unknown provider: $rootScope Provider <- $rootScope  <- myService
However, this works if I just use shortcut syntack for decalring dependencies:

> function myService($rootScope, ngDialog) {
>
> //$rootScope here is accessible
>
> }

But this approach is not minification-safe.
So the question is: how do I create new scope in a service?

**UPDATE**
Here is the jsfiddle that shows the structure I had in the project. The error occurred when service was called from the directive, and now the problem is gone.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga6Ltzyp/1/)

Comment: `ngDialog requires scope object to be passed as parameter` - I don't think this is correct. Did you try not passing a scope?

Comment: it requires scope to interpolate template. If I don't pass scope, dialog will show up, but I can't change anything inside of it without scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you inject the `$rootScope` and `ngDialog` you still need to specify them in your service.

```
var myservice= function($rootScope, ngDialog) {
  // ...
}

myservice.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'ngDialog'];
someModule.service('myservice', myservice);
```

**Update : This code perfectly works**

```
var myservice = function($rootScope,ngDialog) {
      alert($rootScope);
}

angular.module('myapp',['ngDialog']).controller('datac',function($scope,myservice){
  $scope.parties = [];
  myservice.$inject = ['$rootScope','ngDialog'];
});

angular.module('myapp').service('myservice', myservice);
```

Here is plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/FXrE3jNhAYqtv7vVGzgx?p=preview

**Update : 
Ok sorry i was injecting the service in controller instead just inject the rootScope and ngDialog in service outside the controller**

```
var myservice = function(obscope,obdialog) {
alert(obscope);

}

myservice['$inject'] = ['$rootScope', 'ngDialog'];


angular.module('myapp',['ngDialog']).controller('datac',function($scope,myservice){
  $scope.parties = [];
});

angular.module('myapp').service('myservice', myservice);
```

Comment: Sure! My code is just the same as yours. And this code fails. But If comment line with myservice.$inject, it works!

Comment: The problem occures when I inject the scope\rootScope. If I only inject ngDialog, it works too

Comment: Thanks maddygoround, but it seems that $inject inside a controller doesn't help much. It works because Implicit Annotation is used instead. If you change parameters name in myservice, it would break. It means that $inject is not used for DI, but paramters names are.

Comment: please see the updated code. i made some changes for you which make sense to you :D

Comment: Thanks, maddygoround. You example is working correctly. Unfortunately, I couldn't figured out what was the real reason for error I got, but it is working now, after I recreated it all from the scratch. I updated my first post to show the structure I had